# Eclipse Error "Could not create Java Virtual Machine"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-studio

Error Image: http://postimg.org/image/p5ur9r7yh/

It was working just half an hour ago. But now it's throwing error like it could not create JVM.
I Tired putting Environment variable like said in 
http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-1761312/fix-create-java-virtual-machine-issue.html

Also tried to create registry value _JAVA_OPTIONS

Also tried to change values in eclipse.ini file. Nothing helped!

Comment: The fastest is to remove your environment variables again, and unzip a fresh copy of Eclipse.

Comment: Tried the first part. No use :(

Comment: Then try the second part too.  Do _not_ reuse the workspace.